# Pass query as parameter to express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I currently have an `ejs` file with a table element where each row is clickable like so:
`<tr onclick="myFunction(this)">`

I use javascript to try and pass the query as a parameter in an http request:

```
<script>
        function myFunction(x) {
            num = parseInt(x.cells[0].textContent);
            window.location = '/shownumber?n=num';
        }
</script>
```

In my `routes` file I create the route as follows:

```
app.get('/shownumber', db.getSelectedNum)
```

I then have a `queries.js` file where I try to print out the value using `console.log` (for testing purposes):

```
const getSelectedNum = (request, response) => {
    console.log(n);
}
```

When I click on a table row though I get the following error:

```
ReferenceError: n is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong / how can I properly pass this parameter as a query so I can use it in the `getSelectedNum` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`console.log(n)` will break because you've never defined "n", it doesn't exist.  In order to get it you need to use the `request` with something like `request.query`.

Comment: I am still unable to access the value, ```request.query``` results in: ```{'n': 'num'}```

Comment: Because you sent it 'num' as a string.  ````/shownumber?n=' + num````.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using express, it's already done for you. You can simply use [req.query](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query) for that:

```
let n = request.query.n; // GET["n"]
```

Comment: If I do ```console.log(request.query.n)``` I get the following output: ```num)``` I'm not sure why this is the output it seems like the parameter is just being passed as a string instead of the value I defined.

Comment: That is correct, because you are passing query param value as `'/shownumber?n=num'` which is nothing but `num`
You need to do something like this using string interpolation 

` `/shownumber?n=${num}` `
ref : https://careerkarma.com/blog/javascript-string-interpolation/